# Do dictionaries sometimes say nonsense?

Tags: formality

For example, plural nouns like 'clothes' and 'pants' actually are singulars, but we call them 'plural nouns.' If it's true, what words is appropriate to describe these cases? 'Formal'?

Comment: Grammatically, they're plural. We say, "my pants are too tight", not,  "my pants is too tight".

Comment: Can we say they are plurals? Do they just function as plurals?

Comment: The dictionary needs to tell you both what the word means and how it is used.

Comment: They are simply described as plural nouns: https://www.lexico.com/grammar/plural-nouns-treated-as-singular. Nothing else. There are lots of them: tweezers, trousers, scissors, gymnastics...

Comment: @yourfriend - why do you think that 'clothes' is singular?

Comment: because the definition is singular...?

Comment: Plural and singular are matters of grammar, not of semantics.

Comment: I got it it's like a gender form

Comment: clothes noun [ plural ] things such as dresses and trousers that you wear to cover, protect, or decorate your body - Cambridge Dictionary